# Django - adding user authentication to request.META

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I' working on a Django project and to create some graphs using Graphs.js I'm using a class inheriting from the REST Framework's APIView, just like it was explained in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4Vmm3yZPgc.

The code for this:

```
class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        user = User.objects.get(user=request.user)
        gross_and_nets = GrossAndNet.objects.filter(user=user)
        years = []
        gross_values = []
        net_values = []
        for gn in gross_and_nets:
            years.append(gn.get_year())
            gross_values.append(gn.get_gross())
            net_values.append(gn.get_net())
        data = {
            "labels": years,
            "gross_values": gross_values,
            "net_values": net_values,
        }
    return Response(data)
```

My issue is that I'm using a custom user model and the request.user in the get method of ChartData outputs AnonymousUser. Consequently, I followed the instructions in the 'Custom Authentication' section from http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/, and realised that I don't have any username header in request.META. Thus, in

```
def authenticate(self, request):
    username = request.META.get('X_EMAIL')
    if not username:
        return None
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')
    return (user, None)
```

I don't have any header to retrieve the user's email, which is the primary identifier. To this I've tried adding a header in the main View's get method like:

```
class KPIDemoView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'demo_view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(KPIDemoView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        full_context = try_get_context(context, self.request.user)
        return full_context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(KPIDemoView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response['X_EMAIL'] = request.user.email
        return response
```

But I've had no luck. Essentially the question is: how to add the user's email to the HTTP header so that I can retrieve it using request.META.get('X_EMAIL'). I've also tried get('HTTP_X_EMAIL'), as it is frequently suggested.

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using, token based, djagno session base?

Comment: Must be django session base. Followed the instructions from cfe's custom user auth tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HshbjK1vDtY

Comment: if `request.user` is `AnonymousUser` than there is no authenticated user in session

Comment: May I know, how is this API consumed. While making a call to this API. Something like this
`requests.get(url,headers={'X_EMAIL': 'some_email'})`